# Generating and downloading folder of .docx files with Flask

Tags: python, flask, filesystems

I'm currently learning how to use Flask, and my goal is to let the user provide certain inputs, click Generate, and then Download a .zip file of .docx files generated by a different python script.

Currently, my .docx generation python script saves the folder locally, which I don't think is ideal. It is saved as a folder of .docx files, so what is the best way to have those files able to be downloaded by a user who inputted variables that generated those files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) module and [flask.send_from_directory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.send_from_directory) are what you need